# Python character check and replacement

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæø˚a ?"
Text = input("Text input")
```

How do I replace a character in input with `?` if its not in alphabet?

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: having `'?'` in alphabet will make the results confusing though. You will not be able to tell whether it *always was* a ? or if it became one. Also note that the replacement will not take place **as you type**. If that is what you want to achieve, you have to rephrase your question a bit.

Comment: for checks `a in b` use sets - they are faster as lists (or iterable strings). `alphabet = set ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæø˚a ?')` and `Text = ''.join( (x for x in input("Text input") if x in alphabet))`

Answer (score 4):

You can check if an input character is in `alphabet` and replace it with `'?'` if it's not there.

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæø˚a ?'
text = input('Text input: ')

print(''.join(['?' if x not in alphabet else x for x in text]))
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is other way if, Austins answers was too difficult to understand.

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæø˚a ?"
Text = input ("Text input")
i = 0;
for letter in Text:
    if letter not in alphabet:
        Text =Text[:i] + '?' + Text[i+1:]
    i = i+1
print (Text)
```

here the changed character is also saved to the string `Text`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæø˚a\? "

text = input("Text input")
new_text = re.sub('[^' + alphabet + ']', '?',text)
```

Not pretty but it works